# How to mass-check for duplicates in MS-Access and log changes?

Tags: sql, ms-access, logging, sql-update

I want to mass-compare a few hundred fields in MS Access between 2 tables with identical column structures. If there are any differences between the column values, replaces the row in table1 with the new row in table2. If table2 does no longer holds a row that exists in table1, that row should be dropped from table1. All changes to table1 should be logged in tableLOGS.

Take for example:

```
____table1___     _____table2____     __________tableLOGS__________
| pid | A | B |   | pid | A | B |     | id | pid | A | B | action |
|  1  | 0 | 0 |   |  1  | 0 | 0 |     |  1 |  1  | 0 | 0 |  add   | 
|  2  | 0 | 0 |   |  2  | 0 | 1 |     |  2 |  2  | 0 | 0 |  add   |
|  3  | 0 | 0 |
```

After running the desired SQL query, the result should be:

```
____table1___     _____table2____     __________tableLOGS__________
| pid | A | B |   | pid | A | B |     | id | pid | A | B | action |
|  1  | 0 | 0 |   |  1  | 0 | 0 |     |  1 |  1  | 0 | 0 |  add   | 
|  2  | 0 | 1 |   |  2  | 0 | 1 |     |  2 |  2  | 0 | 0 |  add   |
                                      |  3 |  2  | 0 | 1 |  edit  |
                                      |  4 |  3  | 0 | 0 | delete |
```

I expect this would have to be broken down into 2 separate queries?

Mass-compare rows and update changes Log the changes to tableLOGS This seems like a fairly common task so perhaps MS Access has an easy way of accomplishing this? Thanks for all the help! :)

P.S. I am also open to simply deleting rows from table1 that do not match table2, and INSERT INTO table1 from table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from memory I didn't actually run this so it may need some fixing.  My apologies

Start with the logging for updates

```
  INSERT INTO TableLogs
   SELECT A, B
   FROM (
    SELECT A, B
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.pid = t2.pid 
       AND (t1.A <> t2.a OR t1.B <> t2.B)
    WHERE table1.A IS NOT NULL)
```

Then update table1 with the updated values

```
  UPDATE table1
  INNER JOIN(
    SELECT *
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.pid = t2.pid 
      AND (t1.A <> t2.a OR t1.B <> t2.B)
    WHERE table1.A IS NOT NULL) t2
  ON table1.pid = t2.pid
```

Log missing records in table 1

```
  INSERT INTO tablelogs
  SELECT A, B
  FROM table2 
   INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.pid = t2.pid AND (t1.A <> t2.a OR t1.B <> t2.B)
   WHERE table1.A IS NOT NULL
```

Delete the missing rows from table1

```
DELETE table1
WHERE pid NOT IN
     (SELECT pid FROM Table2)
```

You could also put a trigger on table1 to update table logs but its not really best practice.

Hope that helps, like I said I didn't run it yet.